# How can we describe 'vector field'?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm learning about differential geometry and I have a question.
For a smooth manifold $M$ and given chart $(U_\alpha,x_\alpha)$ containing specific point $p$, I can describe a vector field $X$ or tangent vector $v_p$ **locally** such as

$X(p)=\sum X^i(p) ~\frac{d}{d x^i}$, $v_pf=\sum v^i ~\frac{df}{dx^i}$ for $f\in C^\infty(M)$

My question is: how can I describe tangent vector X **globally** ?
I can do that on a special manifold, 'Euclidean space', just using the trivial chart.

But how about real projective space $R P^n$ equipted 3 well known charts $(U_1,x_1),(U_2,x_2),(U_3,x_3)$ s.t. $U_i=\{(u_1,u_2,u_3)|u_i\ne 0\}$ and $x_i([u_1,u_2,u_3])=(u_a/u_i,u_b/u_i)$ where $a<b$ are not $i$?

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: It's a section of the tangent bundle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle

Answer (score 1):

A vector field is a map $X: M \to TM$ i.e for the local definition,  given $p \in  U$ we have $X_p: T_pM \to \mathbb{R}$. Here $TM$ is the tangent bundle of $M$.